# Клонировать элемент с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. На странице есть такой элемент, он используется несколько раз:

```
<select class="form-control" name="prof[]">
<option value="0">Выбрать...</option>
<option value="дворник">дворник</option>
<option value="водитель">водитель</option>
<option value="разнорабочий">разнорабочий</option>                            
</select>
```

Мне нужно помочь с куском кода (точнее с функцией) на jQuery, который будет забирать в переменную  либо весь код этого селекта, либо только option'ны. При условии, что  name формы известен. 
Грубо говоря, нужно, чтобы переменная содержала следующее:

```
var forms = '<option value="0">Выбрать...</option><option value="дворник">дворник</option><option value="водитель">водитель</option><option value="разнорабочий">разнорабочий</option>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что оптимальный вариант, это добавление нужного кода по классу, добавляете к тем селектам, куда нужно вставить пункты класс `.add-options` и пишите в JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.add-options').append('<option value="0">Выбрать...</option><option value="дворник">дворник</option><option value="водитель">водитель</option><option value="разнорабочий">разнорабочий</option>');
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/mvn3jrha/)

**UPD**. Изменил код, теперь добавление работает по кнопке, а код берётся из селекта, который уже есть на странице, при условии, что известен name этого селекта:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = $('select[name="prof[]"]').html();
    var index = 4; // Чтобы делать новые селекты с уникальными name, можно использовать переменную, которая будет увеличиваться на 1 после создания нового селекта.
    $('#addSelect').click(function() {
        $('.form').append('<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control add-options" name="prof' + index + '[]">' + options + '</select></div>')
        index++;
    });
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/mvn3jrha/2/)

Comment: Спасибо, но, видимо, я не совсем корректно поставил задачу. Дело в том, что у меня при рендеренге страницы из базы грузится 4 вот таких поля на странице. После чего ниже есть кнопка, которая добавляет эти селекты до бесконечности, но они уже не пыхой, а jQuery добавляются. А так как при рендеренге страницы набор этих самых option'нов может быть разным, поэтому нужно взять инфу из уже отрендеренных и засунуть в генерируемые на jQuery

Comment: @barseon, обновил ответ

Comment: @MasterAlex потеряли скобку в селекторе) и зачем так заморачиваться, просто клонируйте. copypaste

Comment: @lampa, спасибо, поправил, странно. но работало и без неё, а по поводу функции clone(), я бы не рекомендовал её использовать в данном случае, потому что нужно придётся клонировать каждый раз, это сложнее, чем просто сохранить html в переменную и вставлять любое количество раз

Comment: @MasterAlex а я тоже пропустил сначала, ошибки в консоль вываливались. Поэтому и заметил сразу)

Comment: @lampa, в хроме не вываливается :)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/mvn3jrha/3/

```
var form_name = $'input').val();
$("select[name='"+form_name+"']").clone().insertBefore(this);
```